# splash screen and boot startup audio not working in android lollipop and marshmallow

Tags: android

1. I am working on the Android Splash Screens.My Question is How to display a  .img/.bmp/.png format  File for 2 to  5 Seconds before it goes to the Next step (i.e. boot animation ).In Kit Kat its working but for Lollipop (5.1.1) and Marshmallow (6.0.1) how can I do it ?
2. My 2nd question is how to get the Start-up tone(poweron.ogg) when power on the device. It's not worked in Lollipop(5.1.1)and Marshmallow(6.0.1) how can I do it ?

Comment: provide some code. Splash class, layouts etc

Comment: Can you told me details ? Android application (.apk) for splash screen are working fine but my question is related to android customized boot screen for Lollipop (5.1.1) and Marshmallow (6.0.1).